# Interpolate JSON in React Component's attribute?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a React component whose value I would like to set via JSON in the attribute. However, I'd like concatenate a letter or word, but neither show up. Is there a proper way to concatenate strings inside of a Component's attribute? Here, I'm setting the `detail` attribute of a TableView cell.

```
<Cell cellstyle="RightDetail" accessory="DisclosureIndicator" 
title="Height" 
detail={this.state.height} onPress={this.navHeight.bind(this)}/>
```

Which produces this: `175` (the value set for height).

I'd like to find a way to do something like:

```
detail="\{this.state.height} meters"
```

Is this possible to do in React/ES6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the backtick notation if you're in ES6,

```
detail={`${this.state.height} meters`}
```

Per here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals